# SQLITE Exception:Database is Locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am developing an app for ipad and i am using sqlite sentences (select, update, insert, delete).

I open (sqlite3_open) the database at the beginning and close (sqlite3_close) at the end of each sentence. But sometimes i´ve got the "database is locked" message.

I don´t know what can i do to solve this.

```
-(BOOL )executeInsertQuery:(NSString *)query
{
[self copyIfDbNeeded];
BOOL returnValue = YES;
sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = nil;
databaseDB = nil;
if (sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Can now use sqlite on multiple threads, using the same connection");
}

int ret = sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(1);
if(ret != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Not Shared");

}
if (sqlite3_open([self writableDBPath], &databaseDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if(insertStmt == nil)
    {
        const char *sql = [query UTF8String];


        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseDB, sql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"databaseDB Error while creating addStmt in addRecipeToDatabase %@",   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_errmsg(databaseDB)]);
            returnValue = NO;
        }

    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmt))// Execute sqlite statement.
    {
        NSLog(@" databaseDB Error while Executing addStmt in addRecipeToDatabase %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_errmsg(databaseDB)]);
        returnValue = NO;
    }

    sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);// reseting statement.

    if (insertStmt)
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStmt);// finalizing statement.
        insertStmt = nil;
    }

}
sqlite3_close(databaseDB);
return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Sqlite is implemented in C and C doesn't have exceptions.  Anyway I'd say you have an issue with the open/query/close semantics used by this function.  If this method (or another one like it) is called in parallel then sqlite won't be able to open the database (I think).  You should open/close outside of your queries and only open the database when it's not already open and close it when it's no longer in use.

Comment: trojanfoe has a valid point there. Also: `copyIfNeeded` should be run only when application starts - it's purpose is (usually) to copy default database file from app bundle to documents folder.